# gdebi-core isn't recognized as a command

Tags: minecraft, webmin, gdebi

I am trying to host a minecraft server and I found a pdf which tells me to do this:

[image]

So I followed these commands but when I tried the command:

`gdebi-core webmin_1.620_all.deb`

I get the message:

```
gdebi-core:command not found
```

When I try :

```
sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.620_all.deb
```

I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Actually it is gdebi and not gdebi-core while using. I have updated the answer.

Comment: do as `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to install gdebi-core . you can install it with

`sudo apt-get install gdebi-core` and then type as

```
sudo gdebi webmin_1.620_all.deb
```

( Or )
Direct way

```
sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.620_all.deb
```

this is also used to install .deb files in Ubuntu.

Comment: I did install gdebi-core look at the picutre. I'll try the direct way now

Comment: @Loko ok Let me know.

Comment: See my edit. It didnt work.

Comment: @Loko thats the problem with dependencies and `sudo apt-get install -f` can fix the issue.

Comment: You should really stop using `dpkg -i` if the package has dependencies. `gdebi` is smart enough to do stuff.

Comment: Yeah just edit the answer without the dpkg. the gdebi normally worked for me. As I am a complete noob I didn't knew it should be gdebi instead of gdebi-core

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are wrong, you should be using `gdebi webmin_1.620_all.deb`. That will take care of the dependency problem. Just do:

```
sudo gdebi webmin_1.620_all.deb
```

It will take care of all dependencies issues, which `dpkg -i` does not.